# Waiting for completing of asynchronous operations

Tags: boost, boost-asio

HI all!

There is an io_service object, methods run() works in a thread pool.
There are set of classes, which make async write using ip::tcp::socket.
I need to block destructor of this kind of class, until his tasks live in the io_service's queue.
In example, to add method join(). But what the reason to block the destructor?

Comment: "competing" or "completing" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/7665b7170b3311085fff2e84710d4350

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to make sure that classes that are waiting for outstanding async operations are not destroyed before the operation completes?

The [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) idiom can be used for this purpose and is demonstrated e.g. in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime7/src.html. If you look at tcp_connection::start you see how the class passes a shared_ptr to itself to bind as the handler for the async operation.

Comment: @niXman: if you use shared_from_this() when you specify your async write handler, you don't need to worry about blocking in the destructor. The shared_ptr will manage the lifetime of the context class.

Comment: I'm not insteresting when these objects will be dead. I need to catch the moment in the destructor when all his async operations will be finished. This prolem solved like this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/7665b7170b3311085fff2e84710d4350